# Redirecting input/output of execvp

Tags: c, system-calls

I want to redirect the output to a specific file when the program encounters a ">" and for it to get the input from a file if it finds a "<".

This works for the input, but when I try the output to file it doesn't write anything in the actual file nor does it show it in the terminal.

I can't seem to figure out why, can anyone help?

```
switch(fork()){
    case 0:

        for(i=0; i<num; i++){

            if(strcmp(argv[i], ">") == 0){
                if(fd1 = open(argv[i+1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0){
                    perror("cant open file");
                    exit(0);                    
                }
                dup2(fd1, 1);
                close(fd1);
                argv[i] = NULL;
            }

            if(strcmp(argv[i], "<") == 0){
                if(fd0 = open(argv[i+1], O_RDONLY) < 0){
                    perror("cant open file");
                    exit(0);                    
                }
                dup2(fd0, 0);
                close(fd0);
            }

        }

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

Comment: Are you trying to invoke this with `<` or `>` from the shell?

Comment: @BurnsBA yes, for example i'd run "ls > filename" and I want the output to go to the file, it creates the file but doesn't write anything on it

Comment: What did you write to the file?

Comment: Also, you're closing the file descriptor immediately after redirecting.

Comment: Also also, it's generally bad form to co-opt shell commands for your own purposes, I'd recommend command line arguments like `-i` and `-o`

Comment: @J...S I don't understand what you mean? I want the output of the command I run, be it cat, wc, ls to go to a file

Comment: @BurnsBA, he's closing the file descriptor *after duping it*.  This is normal, and under some circumstances it is even necessary.  The file remains open as long as there are any open file descriptors associated with it.

Comment: @codetective, you do not check the return value of the `dup2()` calls to detect possible errors.  I doubt those calls are failing, but you should nevertheless be sure to check.

Comment: You should run your code in a debugger to try to ascertain what's going on.  The `fork()ing` makes that trickier, but not impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is that the `=` operator has lower precedence than the `<` operator.  Thus, in your expression

> ```
> fd1 = open(argv[i+1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0
> ```

, the return value of `open()` is compared to 0, and then the result of that comparison -- either 1 or 0 -- is assigned to `fd1`.  The newly-opened file descriptor is lost, and goes unused.  The actual result of the comparison is most likely 0 (the file was successfully opened), so your `dup2()` call a few lines later attempts to dupe file descriptor 0 onto file descriptor 1.  In all likelihood that works, but any attempt by the program you exec to write to that file descriptor very likely fails.

You ought to write it as

```
(fd1 = open(argv[i+1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0
```

Alternatively, be a little less clever and separate that into two statements, so that the precedence question does not arise in the first place.

You have the same problem when you redirect input, so I'm doubtful of your claim that "This works for the input", but because in that case you'll end up just duping file descriptor 0 onto itself, the problem will manifest simply as the redirection not working as expected -- input will still come from the original program's standard input, not the standard input you designate.

Even that might go unnoticed, however, if you allow the shell to perform the input redirection instead of quoting the redirection operator so as to get it through to the program as an argument.

Comment: I'd argue that it's much more understandable to write `int fd1 = open(...); if ( fd1 < 0 ) { ... }`.  And that doing an assignment in an `if` clause is **bad code**.

Comment: You're right, the input wasn't working, I just thought it was. I've fixed the precedence issue but it still doesn't work

Comment: I fixes the precedence issue and removed the part which attempts to treat the input. Without that part the output now works, it writes in the file, but if both are there it doesn't. I edited the post

Comment: @codetective, this is a question & answer site, not a discussion forum.  If you have a new problem then write a new question.  And if you do so, then be sure to present a [mcve] -- no one is likely to be able to guess your new problem from what you edited into the present question.

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot, not surprised, the problem was what you indicated, the other problem was mine, not on the code. Thank you