# paths must precede expression: `>' in find of execvp c code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    char *argv[6] = {"/home", "-name", "'*.txt'", ">", "all_txt_files.txt", NULL};
    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);    
    execvp("find", argv);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the in the bash `find /home -name '*.txt' > Jerry.txt` that works just fine. But when I run the c code above, it always gives an error `` /home: paths must precede expression: `>' ``
Looks like nonsense, can someone help?
Using WSL 1 in windows 10.

Comment: The redirection you are attempting to use is a shell feature, but there is no shell here. Just open a file handle first, and connect `find`'s standard output to that file handle. I expect this is a common FAQ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648120/redirecting-input-output-of-execvp

Comment: Note also that in your C code, even if you would not get this error, `find` would searching for files where the name starts with an _apostrophe_. The reason is the same as pointed out by tripleee: There is no bash involved which would remove the quotes around _*.txt_.

Comment: @user1934428 nevermind, I didn't get what he said anyway. Strange, that find works fine without the > sign, if it's needed to output the filenames to the screen only.

Comment: The `>` instructs the shell to redirect the standard output of a process to a file. Initially (i.e. when you start a program from inside your terminal and are in an interactive shell), the standard output is collected from your Terminal program and displayed on the screen, so that you can see what's going on.

Comment: May I also suggest, that you remove the _bash_ tag? There is no bash involved in your question.

Comment: Though somewhat less efficient than doing the output redirect yourself, you could also get a shell to be involved using `system("find ... > all_text_files.txt");` or `const char *argv[] = {"-c", "find ... > all_text_files.txt", NULL}; execv("/bin/sh", argv);`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of your example from the viewpoint of the `find` program. When `find` is started using your `execvp`, it gets in its `argv` vector the following parameters:

1. /home
2. -name
3. '*.txt'
4. '>'
5. all_txt_files.txt
6. NULL

When you invoke `find` from the command line, the shell sets up the redirection and `find` sees the following parameters:

1. /home
2. -name
3. *.txt
4. NULL

As you can see, the parameters differ in number and content. It is not a surprise that you get a different outcome.

Do do the same in your shell program, you would have either to mimic what the shell is doing.